# No tables in abi file

Tags: smart-contract

I am trying to write a smart contract but for some reason my tables aren't being added to the abi file and therefore aren't being added to the blockchain.

My code is as follows. Am I possibly declaring the table incorrectly?

```
#include <eosiolib/eosio.hpp>
#include <eosiolib/print.hpp>

using namespace eosio;

class hyperion : public contract
{
  public:
    hyperion(name self, name code, datastream<const char *> ds) : contract(self, code, ds){}

    struct [[eosio::table]] domains
    {
        uint64_t key;            //Primary key
        std::string domain_name; //Domain name
        name owner;              //Owner of the domain
        uint32_t price;          //Cost of the domain

        uint64_t primary_key() const { return key; }
    };

    typedef eosio::multi_index<"domains"_n, domains> domain_index;

    [[eosio::action]] 
    void upsert(name user, std::string domain_name, uint32_t price)
    {
        //Require auth from the user
        require_auth(user);
        //Get the domains
        hyperion::domain_index domains(_code, _code.value);
        //Check if the domain exists in the table
        bool found = false;        
        for (auto itr = domains.begin(); itr != domains.end() && found != true; ++itr)
        {
            if (itr->domain_name == domain_name)
            {
                found = true;
            }
        }
        if (!found)
        {
            domains.emplace(user, [&](auto &row) {
                row.key = domains.available_primary_key();
                row.domain_name = domain_name;
                row.owner = user;
                row.price = price;
            });
        }
    }
};

EOSIO_DISPATCH( hyperion::hyperion, (upsert) )
```

Comment: The only obvious problem is that you haven't declared that the `hyperion` class is a contract with `[[eosio::contract]]`. Try that and if it still doesn't work, then update the question to include the steps you use to build the wasm and abi files please